# Help with testing a Case Email Trigger

Tags: trigger, email, case, code-coverage

Someone on the forum was gracious enough to help me with the below code. Basically, it checks if a case is closed and there is incoming email, it will then clone the case.

Problem is how can I replicate an incoming message in a test class to test the trigger. I can create the new case and change its status to closed with the close, but would be the best way to replicate a new incoming email in the code. Is there an incoming email flag.

Thanks in advance.

```
trigger AutoCloneCase on EmailMessage (after insert) {
Set<ID> caseSet = new Set<ID>();
List<Case>cloneList = new List<Case>();
for (EmailMessage so : Trigger.new) {
    if(((String)so.parentid).startsWith('500') && so.Incoming){
        caseSet.add(so.parentid); 
    } 
}
Map<Id,case> caseMAP = new Map<Id,case>([SELECT id, isClosed, Type, Auto_Closed__c FROM Case WHERE id in:caseSet]);  
for(Case c:caseMAP.values()){
    if(c.IsClosed && c.Type == 'Support' && c.Auto_Closed__c == true) {
        Case cloneCase = c.clone(false,true);
        cloneCase.parentid=c.id;  
        cloneList.add(cloneCase);
    }
}
try { 
    insert cloneList;      
} catch(DMLException e) {   
     System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage()); 
}
}
```

Then for the test.

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true)
private class TestSupportTrigger{
static testMethod void myUnitTest() {      
    Case c = new Case(Severity__c = '4 (General Support)',  Origin = 'Self Service   Portal', Subject = 'Unit Test', Type = 'Support', Status = 'Closed', Time_Spent__c = 5, Auto_Closed__C = true );
    insert c;

    EmailMessage[] newEmail = new EmailMessage[0];
    newEmail.add(new EmailMessage(FromAddress = 'someone@somewhere.com', Incoming = True, ToAddress= 'someone@salesforce.com', Subject = 'Test email', TextBody = 'Test', ParentId = c.Id)); 

    Test.startTest();     
    insert newEmail;
    Test.stopTest();         
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an EmailMessage in your test case and insert it. Your trigger will fire.

E.g.

```
static testMethod void lmgtfy() {

    // TODO: Create and Insert a test Case here with isClosed = true and Type = 'Support'
    Case c = //...

    EmailMessage em = new EmailMessage();
    em.FromAddress = 'test@example.com';
    em.Incomming = true;
    em.ToAddress = 'hello@670ocglw7xhomi4oyr5yw2zvf.8kp7yeag.8.case.salesforce.com';
    em.Subject = 'Test email';
    em.TextBody = 'Hello';
    em.ParentId = c.Id; // The inserted test Case Id that you created above

    Test.startTest();
    insert em;
    Test.stopTest();

    // TODO: Make assertions that the new cloned cases have been created.

}
```

Comment: Great. If you consider this a valid answer to your question the convention is to use the green tick to mark it as such. It helps other users find the accepted answer.